# Subsetting Data in R to Plot Constrained Data

Tags: r

I have a data set (in R) called data which contains information about petrol and one of the columns is “Site_Brand” which contains the name of the petrol station (e.g. 7 Eleven)

I want to subset this data (or constrain it) so that only rows with “7 Eleven”, “Caltex” or “Costco” are retained.

I have tried using 
myvars <- c(“7 Eleven", "Caltex", "Costco")
newdata <- data[myvars]
However, when I plot this in a graph, the data just doesn't appear at all.
Thanks in advance!

Here's the most recent code I have tried ...

```
# using subset function
data <- subset(data, data$Site_Brand == "7 Eleven" | data$Site_Brand == "Caltex",)

newData <- data[c("7 Eleven", "Costco", "Caltex"), ]

# Grouped Bar Plot
counts <- table(newData$Site_Brand, newData$Fuel_Type)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
  xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
  legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to `grep` on the column with site names to get the ones you want. Here's an approach using `data.table` (make it easier to `subset`):

```
library(data.table)

# Creating a data.table with some sample data
dat <- data.table(site_name = c('montreal costco', 'laval 7 elevel', 'sherbrooke shell', 
                                'montreal 7 eleven', 'laval costco', 'laval ultramar'), 
                  prices = rnorm(n = 6, mean = 1.3, sd = 0.3))

> dat
           site_name   prices
1:   montreal costco 1.050324
2:    laval 7 elevel 1.521547
3:  sherbrooke shell 1.079738
4: montreal 7 eleven 1.166546
5:      laval costco 1.094838
6:    laval ultramar 1.243748


> dat[ grep(pattern = '(costco)|(eleven)', x = site_name, ignore.case = T), ]
           site_name   prices
1:   montreal costco 1.050324
2: montreal 7 eleven 1.166546
3:      laval costco 1.094838
```

If you don't want to use `data.table`:

```
> subset(dat,subset = grepl(pattern = '(costco)|(eleven)', dat$site_name, ignore.case = T))
           site_name   prices
1:   montreal costco 1.050324
2: montreal 7 eleven 1.166546
3:      laval costco 1.094838
```

You can also use the `%in%` operator to supply a set of acceptable values that the column can have. This approach requires to supply complete names and the proper case (although you can use `tolower` to get around that) as opposed to the more general approach `grep`:

```
> dat[site_name %in% c('costco', 'eleven'), ]
Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): site_name,prices

> dat[grep(pattern = '(costco)|(eleven)', x = site_name, ignore.case = T), ]
           site_name   prices
1:   montreal costco 1.050324
2: montreal 7 eleven 1.166546
3:      laval costco 1.094838
```

Note:

1. I'm using `ignore.case` to account for inconsistencies in upper/lower case
2. For `7 eleven` I'm using `eleven` alone in my pattern search
   assuming the two always show up together
3. This will not be able to catch misspelled names e.g. row 2 in `dat` where eleven is misspelled as elevel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

newData <- data %>%
  filter(Site_Brand %in% c("7 Eleven", "Costco", "Caltex"))
```

Alternatively:

```
newData <- data[data$Site_Brand %in% c("7 Eleven", "Costco", "Caltex"), ]
```